# When to use Java Thread API

Tags: java, multithreading

Personally I am using [high level concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) abstractions cause they are much easier. Actually I cannot remember the last time I have used a theads. But on the technical interview it is a frequently asked question. And yeah I ask about it too.

Are there any use cases when it is necessary to use low level Thread API instead of Executors/Locks/Latches/etc.?

Is there any reason to discuss low level thread API during the technical interview?

Comment: Perhaps they are still using 1.4 where these abstractions are not available? Worrying, but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement something very specific, you're stuck with legacy code, an old version of Java or you need an abstraction that's not provided, then I'd consider using the raw low level threading API. Even when there's an old version / legacy code in use though bear in mind that making the switch to the newer API may well be worth it if it drives maintenance down - personally I try to keep the amount of user generated concurrent code at a minimum!

Answer (score 4):

Technical interviews are often designed to measure the depth of the candidate's knowledge, not any particular ability. Arguably, there has been no need to implement your own linked lists and binary trees for good 15..20 years, yet the questions asking to implement these data structures routinely come up in technical interviews. A smart candidate *should be able to* figure out high-level concurrency APIs from a short tutorial and the API docs. You ask about thread primitives to see if the candidate *understands* what is happening behind the scenes when he or she uses concurrency in general, no matter what API is called.

Personally, when I ask questions about things you'd never use, I do not insist on getting the correct names or the right order of the API method parameters. As long as the candidates are clear on the concept, I do not mind them not remembering the particulars of the specific API.

Comment: is there any reason to walk through join, wait, notify, notifyAll stuff?

Comment: @MairbekKhadikov I would go through them very briefly, just to see that the candidate understands what they do in general, without getting into much details of how to call them correctly. For example, I'd ask "what's the difference between notify and notifyAll", rather than "show me how to call notify".